# How to pronounce the '/100 km'?

Tags: pronunciation

Hi, there!

When we describe the fuel consumption, how should we pronounce the ***'/100km'***?

e.g: This car has a fuel consumption of 100 gal/100km.

Is it pronounced as 'per one hundred kilometers' or 'per hundred kilometers'? Or do we say 'every hundred kilometers'?
Or any other solutions?

I appreciate any suggestions. 
Thank you a lot!

---

I've read all the comments, and thank you for your detailed answers.

I searched for some materials and found that there are varies ways to express fuel consumption:

1. Miles Driven divided by Amount of Gas Used:

   - Units:

     1. Miles per gallon (mpg, mi/gal, MPG, used in the U.S.A and the U.K.)
     2. Kilometer per liter (km/L)
2. Amount of Gas Used divided by Miles Driven:

   - Units:

     1. Liters per 100 kilometers (L/100km)
     2. Liters per mile (L/mi, used in Norway and Sweden)

---

Thank you all again for all the comments!

Comment: Any of the above.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_) has: 'The slash in derived units such as m/s (meters per second) is not an abbreviation slash, but a straight division.' The expansion almost certainly licenses _one_ way of pronouncing this, and it's the one I've always used.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense whatsoever. If it costs you a hundred gallons of fuel to drive barely sixty miles and change, you'd go broke before you got anywhere.

Comment: @tchrist. I bet a Falcon heavy rocket uses more than 100 gallons before reaching 100 kilometers ***upwards**!*

Comment: Nah, what doesn't make sense is to mix up gallons and kilometers in a European-style expression of fuel economy.

Comment: There is no rule; it's entirely subjective. How do you pronounce *1011*? Is it *one thousand and eleven*, *one thousand eleven*, or *ten eleven?* This is one of the main reasons why numbers in dialogue are spelled out rather than presented as numerals—so that the characters' pronunciation is made clear.

Comment: @choster That's right: fuel economy should be in miles/gallon or parsecs/joule or some such.

Comment: @choster — kilometers a European expression? In the two English-speaking European countries it’s the original French spelling, kilometres. (But, in Britain we buy our petrol (gasoline) in litres, but our distances are in miles.) Sounds Irish, I know, but in Ireland they actually use kilometres and litres.

Comment: @David What I mean is that expressing fuel economy as consumption per fixed distance traveled is European (and antipodean; typically L/100km). In the US, much of Asia, and Latin America, it is given as distance per unit of fuel consumed by volume (in the US typically mi/gal, usually abbreviated as MPG, elsewhere km/L).

Comment: @choster The standard way to express fuel consumption in much of Europe (at least the northern bits of it) is _km/L_ as well.